# TypeScript: Type guard does not work with switch statement when putting object into variable

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why type guard doesn't work in the example below...

**When we have these interfaces,**

```
interface ParamA {
    name: 'A';
    aaa: boolean;
}

interface ParamB {
    name: 'B';
    bbb: number;
}
```

**Good**

```
function func(param: ParamA | ParamB) {
    switch (param.name) {
        case 'A':
            const aaa = param.aaa;
            console.log(aaa); // boolean
            break;
        case 'B':
            const bbb = param.bbb;
            console.log(bbb); // number
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Bad**

```
function func(param: ParamA | ParamB) {
    const name = param.name; // just rewrite here
    switch (name) {
        case 'A':
            const aaa = param.aaa;
            //                ^^^
            console.log(aaa);
            break;
        case 'B':
            const bbb = param.bbb;
            //                ^^^
            console.log(bbb);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Compiler throws errors like `Property 'aaa' does not exist on type 'ParamB'.` I do not think there should be a difference in behaviors whether I can put it in a variable.

The version of TypeScript using is 2.8.3.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 5):

### Update 2021-08:

[Typescript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#cfa-aliased-conditions) got smarter and your example work out of the box :-)

### Old answer

Assigning the property to a variable looses the connection to the object.
This would be very hard to follow for the compiler as you could change the string and the object variable independently:

```
var param: ParamA | ParamB;
param = someParamA;
const name = param.name;
param = someParamB;
switch (name) { // boom
```

So if you know for sure that you have not changed the variable you can use the type assertion but i would not do that for maintenance reason.

Comment: Is this true? if so i would have expected something like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgQWQbwChkTkRsIAuZAchxoG5jS5XqjTPkwoBPOAOZxQ1EAFcsAI2jMSAX0ILCoSLEQp0mLACECsshWo1tjfZPOiJ0qEyUIA9iADOYZPckArZNU3Y8AXj1OciwqWnoAGn1WOHZ9Th5+IRFkACYAZgAWAFZ9BSVCB2dXV0D3DwA6GMJCMF4ABxQnAAt7MQAbABNtCG17e3aIOBBtMTAAOXtS7gaIexhuGqKXZGaIXmoWtq6evoGhkbHJ6Y5SRMFhEGoANizsu8VCIA to not work

Comment: I have no idea what you want to say with the example. Why should shouldBeBooleanButNot be boolean? It is clear the type of the sub object. Did you linked a wrong example? ParamB is not used at all.

Answer (score 3):

`switch` statement serves as [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in 'good' snippet and doesn't do that in 'bad' one.

> I do not think there should be a difference in behaviors whether I can put it in a variable.

There's no difference in behaviour, there's a difference in how TypeScript is able to analyze this code. Since the code is statically analyzed, the ways how `param` type can be narrowed are limited.

In order for `param` to be narrowed down to `ParamA` or `ParamB` it should be mentioned in type guard. Since it wasn't but `name` variable was,  `param` won't be narrowed down, its type will need to be asserted in this case:

```
...
switch (name) {
    case 'A':
        const aaa = (<ParamA>param).aaa;
...
```