# Typescript match function arguments to key and value of a type map

Tags: typescript, arguments, typescript-typings, typemaps

I have a very simple case, but my experience with Typescript typings is limited and I cannot seem to solve this seemingly simple case.

I have a type map for example like this:

```
interface KeyValueMap {
  key: 'value';
  foo: 'bar';
}
```

Now I would like to type the first and second argument of a function to the key and value of the above map

```
const test = <K extends keyof KeyValueMap>(key: K, value: KeyValueMap[K]) => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'key':
      return value; // currently getting "KeyValueMap[K]" expecting "value"
    case 'foo':
      return value; // currently getting "KeyValueMap[K]" expecting "bar"
  }
};
```

I tried to search for a similar case, but it seems my Google is broken...
So no offense taken when marked as duplicate if such example exists already on Stackoverflow.

### UPDATE

After the comment from @ShivamSingla under my question I realize I might have not been clear enough in my question. I am not interested in the return values of the function, but would already like the type  to be recognized in the actual function logic (within the switch-case). I will change the example to make it more clear:

```
interface KeyObjectMap {
  foo: {
    key1: 'value1';
  };
  bar: {
    key2: 'value2';
  };
}

const test = <K extends keyof KeyObjectMap>(key: K, value: KeyObjectMap[K]) => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'foo':
      return value.key1; // property 'key1' does not exist on 'KeyObjectMap[K]'
    case 'bar':
      return value.key2; // property 'key2' does not exist on 'KeyObjectMap[K]'
  }
};
```

---

**[Here you can find a Playground with this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgNIQJ4HkBGArCBMAWTgAdkBvAKGWRgHsGAuK2u5Aa0wEZWByAG5wANgFcIPfgG52AX1l0ccKKxocumAEwDh4iFpnzZc6tQQMQAZzDJIN5AF5kAHlTIIAD0ggAJlc0MBhg0TFwCIlIyAD4ACm4MVlQAGmQ9CSSw-EIScgBtVABdAEonaLY6KwB3YDAEAAtkeMxS9Q4EOCsUfkYGfmZ2DSgIMDEoEDTRCQA6BJ5pZAB6ReQyKAYyaDAMZH45-mRfBggAkAZbL2AHS130bGzI-KL%20QeQOrt3lKH7XumHR8aTfSzbQLZardabKDbXYJQyHY6nc4eTxXWw3fh3cI5KIFQovOimBRAA)**

Comment: add a default case too. Currently, it is showing `not all the code path return the value`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgNIQJ4DU4BsCuEAsnAA7IDeAUMsgNaYBcyA5AG56EsDcNyMAewHMWAIzhQeVAL5UqYDKRQANZAF56mATDSYcBYmTkIBIAM5hkkC+uQAeVMggAPSCAAmZzRm27snQ1IAPgAKBgxmVAAaZA4DSL0AklIAbVQAXQBKdSDKPjMAd2AwBAALZDDMbOpaWgQ4MxQWcJZGPlrkKAgwfCgQWIDuZAB6YeQEXq7wXAxkAHNusFA55AAidH8DZLT01adnJQQlkBXVuMJV9vGGpsEBVqvaLp6+gYMh0fHJiGnZhbBjqcNvpCNsMnsXIdAWtxFBLh13BB4PhcGA2h0nt1ev18B4kaAIO4+LJZFQTOZLHBbNYwCFmpgWDF2AEWNlPsyDCxkAAfZC4xEwAlE8k2UTUiAWOl3RmsWGskZjMQSLm8-n4kCEoA)

Comment: Why dont you make the "key1" and "key2" as just "key" so that typescript can get that parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `key` and `value` are not associated, value can be re-assigned, before switch case. That's why the error. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50405198/11642727) answer for better understanding.

```js
interface KeyObjectMap {
  foo: {
    key1: 'value1';
  };
  bar: {
    key2: 'value2';
  };
}

type K1 = keyof KeyObjectMap

const test = <K extends K1 = K1>(key: K, value: KeyObjectMap[K]) => {
  // error here, 'key2' is missing
  value = {
    key1: 'value1',
  }

  // value is actually intersection, subtype `KeyObjectMap` actually
  value = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
  }

  // since `key` and `value` are not associated, value can be re-assigned
  // before switch case. That's why the error

  switch (key) {
    case 'foo':
      return value.key1; // property 'key1' does not exist on 'KeyObjectMap[K]'
    case 'bar':
      return value.key2; // property 'key2' does not exist on 'KeyObjectMap[K]'
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgNIQJ4HkBGArCBMAWTgAdkBvAKGWRgHsGAuK2u5Aa0wEZWByAG5wANgFcIPfgG52AX1l0ccKKxocumAEwDh4iFpnzZc6tTAYyKVD2QBeTRgYw0mXASKkyZhAxABnMGRIQPtkAB5UZAgAD0gQABN-NFsHGwA+AApuDFZUABpkPQk8t3xCEnIAbVQAXQBKe3S2OgB6VuioKAYoZAALaAhC-hzDZGBkgFsJ-1AAc3ZilAd1Dhy+ZCFRCSl8+TM2jqXx5MQwMVERDHHwaH8K4D9C-zEcCytkAAN0bHLPck+yDOFxEV0W22WLTWvF0EN27Doo1h+kMezopnY7WQsxASC+OUBcESXyWhKgKBADCCcH8-gYCGAcEgCUKxwQROQOBQ5IAtDTZnMQBAEpiOlzGOTsQB3YBgBB9ZDs+4AOmQABU+kz+MkpX1rmABp1ulADtLZfLkNlMI1VnQlSh+IwGPxmAiOOTzlAQEUIcr1tJkFiyN0rFALJt1vxkAkGBBkpSgrEJkE-Jsfu4Kl4arV+G77ZtlFAXW66B6xF6ffo-doA0GQ9BwyNtFGY3HkAnojFk8hU-x039KmRs7n0dQFEA)

Possible solution

```js
interface KeyObjectMap {
  foo: {
    key1: 'value1';
  };
  bar: {
    key2: 'value2';
  };
}

const test = <O extends Partial<KeyObjectMap>>(obj: O) => {
  if (obj.foo) {
    return obj.foo.key1
  }

  if (obj.bar) {
    return obj.bar.key2
  }

  return undefined
};

// calling
const c = test({foo: {key1: 'value1'}})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgNIQJ4HkBGArCBMAWTgAdkBvAKGWRgHsGAuK2u5Aa0wEZWByAG5wANgFcIPfgG52AX1l0ccKKxocumAEwDh4iFpnzZc6tQQMQAZzDJIN5AF5kAHizIIAD0ggAJleQABRUwYFEXdGx8QhJyAD44gAoGfFYsAEonOLY6YBhkZPwAOkYGTPUOKAgwMSgQZBS8EqYi7gweeTNc-MKm5Shy9joqmrqG4v7W7U72Edr6sT8IGFAIX2oFMwB6LeQEURFQAHNzSwcEJzsIG0TKUrU2vmQhUQkpOTl0oA)