# Generalized generic types do not load abstract type context

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
type ResourceData = {
  user: { id: number; name: string; email: string }
  product: { id: number; name: string; price: number }
  order: { id: number; userId: number; productId: number; quantity: number }
}

type ResourceAction<T extends keyof ResourceData> = {
  type: T
  payload: ResourceData[T]
}

function fetchActionData<T extends keyof ResourceData>(
  action: ResourceAction<T>,
) {
  const actionPayload = action.payload as ResourceData[T] // <---- not working well, it's look only for id.

  switch (action.type) {
    case "product":
      const product = action.payload as ResourceData["product"]
      return `product is ${product.name}`
    case "order":
      const order = action.payload as ResourceData["order"]
      return `order is ${order.productId}`
    case "user":
      const user = action.payload as ResourceData["user"]
      return `name is ${user.name}`
    default:
      return
  }
}

const userAction: ResourceAction<"user"> = {
  type: "user",
  payload: { id: 1, name: "Alice", email: "alice@example.com" },
}

const productAction: ResourceAction<"product"> = {
  type: "product",
  payload: { id: 101, name: "Widget", price: 19.99 },
}

const orderAction: ResourceAction<"order"> = {
  type: "order",
  payload: { id: 1001, userId: 1, productId: 101, quantity: 3 },
}

console.log(fetchActionData(userAction))
console.log(fetchActionData(productAction))
console.log(fetchActionData(orderAction))
```

When I try to remove this code:

```
const product = action.payload as ResourceData['product'];
```

...and make new const on top of switch case:

```
const actionPayload = action.payload as ResourceData[T]
```

after using it:

```
    case "user":
      return `name is ${actionPayload.name}`
```

typescript throws the following error:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ id: number; name: string; email: string; } | { id: number; name: string; price: number; } | { id: number; userId: number; productId: number; quantity: number; }'.
```

and when inspecting `context`, it only contains `id` field.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you can lead your code to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403313/typescript-type-guard-does-not-work-with-switch-statement-when-putting-object-i)

Comment: I mean, define `ResourceData` as `type: 'product', payload: ResourceData['product']`, then it will work. Alternatively you can use the old plain `is` type guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is not able to narrow generic types in the body of a generic function. So when you use `ResourceData[T]` within a code branch where a function argument typed as `T` has been narrowed to `'user'`, for example, TypeScript will not treat that as also narrowing the type `T`.

That means `ResourceData[T]` still includes `ResourceData['order']`, which doesn't have a `name` property, and that's why it complains when you try to access that property.

The reason TypeScript won't narrow your generic type is essentially that it's possible to pass a union type. For example:

```js
const unknownAction = Math.random() > 0.5 ? userAction : productAction;
fetchActionData(unknownAction); // <- fetchActionData<"user" | "product">
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOB7ArgJwMYQCIENg6gF4oBvAKCkqmXglQC5SoBLAE0YDtkBbAIzoA0UDjm4RG8YKmYcA5kIjcczADYSpM2VAC+AilTCpErZOmCMSLdsJ79UQkWPXS5Qw80ydbdHXqpREVFY6CysvPkFqWlQASWsuCPsoQ2NTYDjwuyEAR2QcDmBmUEyfXTJtMjJQSFgEFAwIAEEzZkQOAB4AFSgIAA9gCA5WeCgAawgQRAAzWqQ0TFx8AD4iUn1KavEoTr8DHBAVRBxrODmGxZwAbU6AXXLKqeQOFraoKYhgdAALZsK2i66PX6g2GYwm01m9QWeBwSwAFDgXhxGKcoU0kV0lgBKNb+dBtSRQRF-DgABX2h2Oq2JrQ4ADowBSjqwiSNUfNsDDrjcANxQAD0-Kg7QAtGKRcJEMAoAB3QKjTSyiAqFRCIoAchGh0QowCHBUIDegSsdMq-ngMqK3ygCKRdM2OPI-jxOFoUAARCkTGZ3fR1s68QTpV60tS7YyDszWZCORdLuqQ2Z1byzQHnagPmgOFAAAaJ6XMEYAEhI+bpjgg2hz-pdbvdgWCqF9NbT+I4hIbPmINLaDKZVNdMfOXPVndQyZ5qbTVAzwCzubHLGLJDHDKM3vSrCrk+n6Fd0HVNDo6r908D7elR9QYZJfcjA7ZdVjI6vE6nZ9n85zFaXUBLV-LURKxzHc02CKYcGQFRzBbANP1QDhQMoCoKjINtCSvX5aRRJ8Giwtp2kPaJ1RWYgnSoTZGCI49dkoCNKWsSw2EYABGBwgKoxoVA8CB1QUJRVConBuMwAABPpRDAFQIDpfFuHVXxyknNCg2Sdc0nw5Eh0wTTCPzEjVnIjZwC2BN1KTWjkn7RiwigFiAAY2OEDioHVAB1NhZA+Pi1J41iAE46X8-zFO0ZT0OlMdNJws4dIxUcgmPUjcQokyqLHPj-Xo5lQmYuz7McoQrwyOy3HMzdWMKqBcnyQpiigABmULwtUp5Rg4RAZQ4TTVgAWTwL46VQfJWEQbg4RxFZ7LpABWKAAH4ojoHrGHzTTJ3eT4fiRC44Tajqus0rE+UFYUJU275NIBd0r3dKAAB8PXzd0lkqdDEGkulDlkOELu2kldswpEsWOqAVPbD6ZO+36PkunaYThNbgeO8GkE+6G-quhGouRnkgA)

This becomes more complex when a function takes multiple arguments that refer to a generic type. When that generic type is a union, those different arguments could use it to refer to different members of the same union within the same function call.

[TypeScript 5.3 may include a feature](https://www.totaltypescript.com/typescript-5-3#narrowing-in-generic-functions) that allows *some* narrowing in generic functions, specifically setting a lower bound for generic types. But that wouldn't help in this circumstance.

In the specific case where a generic type doesn't affect a function's return type, it's possible to allow narrowing by using a union for your argument type instead. Multiple arguments that need to be narrowed simultaneously can be managed by using spread syntax with a union of tuple types. For example:

```js
type ResourceData = {
    user: { id: number, name: string, email: string },
    product: { id: number, name: string, price: number },
    order: { id: number, userId: number, productId: number, quantity: number },
}

// Using an immediately indexed mapped type (IIMT) to create a union
type UseResourceDataParams = {
  [Type in keyof ResourceData]: [type: Type, data: ResourceData[Type]];
}[keyof ResourceData]

function useResourceData(...[type, data]: UseResourceDataParams) {
  if (type === 'user') {
    data.name; // <- This is fine
  }
  // ...
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

However, I expect your example function always returns the same type here just because you've wanted to simplify your example. If it needs to return different types, then I think you would either need to use overloads (which can be unsound and difficult to manage/maintain) or use type assertions like you have been doing.

I hope you won't be too averse to using type assertions in this case. Yes, they can cause problems, but they are also a very useful tool for telling the TypeScript compiler about information that it doesn't know about but you know is true. And as you've already discovered, that's exactly what you need to do here to get TypeScript to understand your function.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I already thought about immediately indexed mapping. It is a pity that typescript does not have a ready-made solution like this. But now I don't feel stupid when i get a similar work and I really understand why it happens. That helpful!